# Applying Hover Effect to Entire Cell in List

Tags: swiftui, visionos

I want to apply a hover effect to the entire cell when the user hovers over it. However, I've noticed that the hover effect is only applying to the individual views within the cell, not the entire cell itself.

```swift
Section(header: Text("Schema Items")) {
    ForEach(cards[cardIndex].indentedSchemaItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack {
            Text("text")
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .hoverEffect(.highlight) // This applies hover effect only to the content, not the full cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Apply it to the Section instead of the child elements.

Comment: same phenomenon when applied for the Section, and also important when mouse or eyes "point" to that outer part, then it should also trigger

Comment: What if you give it a unique name for the class like section.NEWTHING so that it knows where to apply it.  And if you are 100% the hover code is correct, try adding !important after the css command to force it to over ride any existing elements values.

Comment: @easleyfixed This is SwiftUI, not HTML and CSS

Comment: yes .. but the formatting is like js in the use of objects and uses css triggered events like "hover", but thanks for clearing this up, I was aware that this is swiftui .. thanks.

Comment: ForEach with indices and self will crash you need a real id

Comment: edit your question, and mention this is for `Vision Pro`, to help the contributors.

Comment: @malhal but the index can not be the "self"

Comment: I think you are just missing a `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` just afer the HStack. In my case works on Vision Pro, it highlights the cell in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `Rectangle` or `RoundedRectangle` in the background of the row, then wrap into `zstack`. Your code will look something like below.

```swift
Section(header: Text("Schema Items")) {
    ForEach(cards[cardIndex].indentedSchemaItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        ZStack {
            // background rectangle
            RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 12, height: 12))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .foregroundStyle(.white.opacity(0.001)) // Hover effect hack. 0.0 wont work
                .hoverEffect()
            HStack {
                Text("text")
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `listRowHoverEffect` to your content.

```
Section(header: Text("Schema Items")) {
    ForEach(cards[cardIndex].indentedSchemaItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack {
            Text("text")
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .listRowHoverEffect(.lift) // <- Here
    }
}
```